# SAFEARRAY type not known when compiling using MIDL

Tags: visual-studio, com, idl, midl

My ODL file looks like this:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[oleautomation, uuid(/* redacted */)]
interface ISomething : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT DoSomething(
        [in]BSTR User,
        [in]VARIANT Object,
        [in]SAFEARRAY Array         // may be NULL
        );
}
```

I'm getting errors:

> 1>.\Something.odl(17): error MIDL2139: type of the parameter cannot
>   derive from void or void * : [ Type 'PVOID' ( Parameter 'Array' ) ]
>   1>.\Something.odl(17): error MIDL2105: pointee / array does not derive
>   any size : [ Field 'rgsabound' of Struct 'tagSAFEARRAY' ( Parameter
>   'Array' ) ] 1>.\Something.odl(17): error MIDL2465: Structures
>   containing conformant arrays must be passed by reference. See MSDN for
>   more details : [ Struct 'tagSAFEARRAY' ( Parameter 'Array' ) ]

If I change the type from `SAFEARRAY` to `SAFEARRAY*` (which I don't believe to be correct?) I get different errors:

> 1>.\Something.odl(17): error MIDL2139: type of the parameter cannot
>   derive from void or void * : [ Type 'PVOID' ( Parameter 'Array' ) ]
>   1>.\Something.odl(17): error MIDL2105: pointee / array does not derive
>   any size : [ Field 'rgsabound' of Struct 'tagSAFEARRAY' ( Parameter
>   'Array' ) ]

Is this simply a case that I need to include some other headers? I'm compiling using the MIDL compiler in VS2013, aparently the command-line looks like this:

```
/iid "./source/Something_i.c" /h "Something.h" /W1 /char signed /notlb /app_config /nologo /dlldata "./source/Something_dlldata.c" /proxy "./source/Something_p.c"
```

Comment: You need to tell it what type of elements are in your SafeArray. For example SAFEARRAY(unsigned char) *Data for an array of unsigned chars.  If the data type of the array elements is variable at runtime you could pass the elements as a SafeArray of VARIANT.

Comment: @JJF I just found this out and was about to answer my own question... if you can add this as an answer (ideally fixing my method signatures) I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it what type of elements are in your SafeArray. For example SAFEARRAY(unsigned char) *Data for an array of unsigned chars. If the data type of the array elements is variable at runtime you could pass the elements as a SafeArray of VARIANT.  For example:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[oleautomation, uuid(/* redacted */)]
interface ISomething : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT DoSomething(
        [in]BSTR User,
        [in]VARIANT Object,
        [in]SAFEARRAY(unsigned char) *Array         // may be NULL
        );
}
```

Comment: Specifying the content-type was my issue, thanks. However when I specify  `SAFEARRAY *` my generated header file looks like `/* [in] */ SAFEARRAY * *Array` which doesn't seem great!

Comment: Not sure why this is a problem.  I'm not sure if you can even pass a SAFEARRAY by value.  What did the midl compiler say when you omitted the '*'?  All it means is that you have to add an additional dereference to get to the data.

Comment: If I specify by-value in the IDL, the C++ header automatically references it by pointer. I assume .net marshalling would simply have an array type.

Comment: I don't have much experience marshalling between managed and unmanaged code.  The COM stuff I did was a loooong time ago...

Comment: Anyway that seems to be a side-issue, maybe it warrants a new question but your answer solves my original problem!

Comment: The SAFEARRAY(type) delcaration already implies one level of indirection. So [in] parameters are `[in] SAFEARRAY(type) v` (which is passed as `SAFEARRAY *`), and [out] parameters are `[out] SAFEARRAY(type) * v` (which is passed as `SAFEARRAY **`)